# Threads, Queue and a serious headache

Tags: c#

I am making a program for days but nothing seems to be working. I want to run (n threads=user sepecified threads ie 1-100) on a listview which has 1st field as email (the list is of 10000 records). Now I want to verify each email and add on the 2nd column the thread id and on the third column the result whether the email is valid or not can anybody help me? With some code and explanation. thanx

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? share some sample code or errors.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't use a ListView as a datastructure. Bind it to some `List<MyClass>`.

Then run your Threads on the ThreadPool (<= .NET 3.5) or using Tasks (.NET4).

The [learn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163427.aspx) about accessing your List<> in a thread-safe way. And then update your ListView using Control.Invoke(), or from a Timer

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a task for the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx). Rather than managing your threads by hand, it provides you with higher-level constructs which will properly use the thread pool and the hardware you have available, and parallelize work.

Comment: I will look into it. What i am making is a simple email verification program using multithreading, listview to verify emails and update the listview with the results.  I am having 
1. running thread (they seem to run one by one not simultaneously)
2. updating the listview with the results

can somebody show me a way to do this i will be greatfull to you forever.

Comment: No the task parallel library will not solve my purpose. something like

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Crawler.aspx

but here the items in the listview are undefined and also the sample uses treeview. I like the code but cannot seem to implement it for my problem

Comment: looks like i have to do it on own. Anyway thanx guys

Comment: ParallelForEach is usually the right thing when looping over a collection. The ThreadId should be unknown to the actual list element.
Any object should only know what it needs to know ;-)